# How can i change pagination type property in swiper on required breakpoint

Tags: javascript, swipe

I need to switch my slider's pagination type on breakpoint using swiper. I tried this code, but something went wrong:

```
const slider = new Swiper(".new-offers__slider", {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  spaceBetween: 30,
  slidesPerGroup: 2,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction",
  },
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      slidesPerGroup: 2,
    },
    1024: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      slidesPerGroup: 4,
      pagination: {
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: If you are able to add to your question exactly what result you want, what result you are getting and what you have tried already (either as a description or in code) then you would be more likely to receive quick and accurate responses.